# Vuforia Sample Crash When Device Doesn't Access To Internet

Tags: android, kotlin, vuforia, augmentedimage

I have an android kotlin augmented image application using vuforia engine and it crashes after sometime when i turn mobiles internet off.  when i use vuforia offline it crashes whit this message :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10 Process: com.example.ganjbazi, PID: 12621 java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to usageservice.prod.vuforia.com/10.10.34.36:443
                                                                                            at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:147)
                                                                                                at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:116)
                                                                                                at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:186)
                                                                                                at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
                                                                                                at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
                                                                                                at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
                                                                                                at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
                                                                                                at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
                                                                                                at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:131)
                                                                                                at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:262)
                                                                                                at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:219)
                                                                                                at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
                                                                                                at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.httpurl.TrackedHttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(TrackedHttpURLConnection.java:314)
                                                                                                at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.httpurl.HttpsURLConnection$.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnection$.java:266)
                                                                                                at com.android.tools.appinspection.network.httpurl.TrackedHttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(TrackedHttpURLConnection.kt:303)                                                                                                    at com.android.tools.appinspection.network.httpurl.HttpsURLConnectionWrapper.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionWrapper.kt:213)
```

I have searched for a few days but can't find anything.

Comment: this feels like a bug. I would suggest to file a ticket here https://github.com/PTCInc/vuforia-engine